# Chrome extension background page restriction after event or setTimeout

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying create an extension that delete the downloads history after some time.
The problem is that when chrome.downloads.erase({}) is inside the timeout it does not work correctly.

This background.js works:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('erasing downloads');
chrome.downloads.erase({});
}
, 0);
```

But this does not:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('erasing downloads');
chrome.downloads.erase({});
}
, 1000);
```

Any idea why?

Is changing the manifest can help or using event page instead of background page?

Comment: Keep this to one question, please.

Comment: I know its related question But the previous question title is too general and does not describe the real problem properly

Comment: Please explain why the duplicate question does not solve your problem.

Comment: @NatanRubinstein No, **this** is not the **real** problem. This is just one of its symptoms.

Comment: I just think that this question is the essence of the problem And it will be easier for others to answer it